# Trying to create a Sparql query using Jena's java api

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I created an Ontology model in Java using the Apache Jena library, and I entered pizza ontology.
I am trying to make a sparql query but the table print is blank, although normaly there are answers to my query.
Am I doing something wrong...?
Here is the code:

```
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF);
String inputFileName="pizza.owl";
InputStream in = FileManager.get().open( inputFileName );
if (in == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
         "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
}
model.read(in, null);

String queryString =
        "prefix pizza: <www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Pizza> "+        
        "prefix rdfs: <" + RDFS.getURI() + "> "           +
        "prefix owl: <" + OWL.getURI() + "> "             +
        "select ?pizza where {?pizza a owl:Class ; "      +
        "rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction. "                  +
        "?restriction owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping ;"  +
        "owl:someValuesFrom pizza:PeperoniSausageTopping" +
        "}";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();

ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
qe.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your prefix declaration is wrong. You have accidentally included the name of the `Pizza` class, and also left off the `http` protocol prefix. Corrected, it should be:

```
"prefix pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#> "+
```

The way prefixes work in RDF and SPARQL is that you replace the `prefix:` with whatever the prefix is defined to be, and the resulting string must *exactly* match the URI of the resource you are trying to match. It must be an exact match - even differences in the case of letters is significant.

By the way, you can also simplify loading the ontology via the `FileManager`:

```
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( 
                                  OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF);
FileManager.get().readModel( model, "pizza.owl" );
```